# Class not being autoloaded

Tags: php, composer-php, psr-4

I've made a little library for myself and I'm trying to autoload it into my laravel project, it installs fine but whenever I try to use the class it simply says it's not found.

I've checked all the classmap files in `vendor/composer` and it doesn't seem to be in any of them.

This is my composer.json for my lib:

```
{
    "name": "my-user/aspect-parser",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "type": "package",
    "require": {
        "nesbot/carbon": "^1.22"
    },
    "autoload": {
      "psr-4": {
        "AspectParser\\": "src/"
      }
    }
}
```

My file structure is:

- AspectParser

  - src

    - Parser.php

Comment: how do you try to instantiate your object? and what the full error exception

Comment: I think the issue was the `type`, I've changed it to library and it adds it to the autoload files. Now I'm just having trouble trying to import it with `use` (error is Class not found). `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'AspectParser\Parser' not found in eval()'d code on line 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with the `type` in `composer.json`. I've changed it to `library` and it adds to the autoload classmap.